# Combinatorics Fundamental - Counting Perspective

Tags: combinatorics

Question 1 :- Number of of distinct ways in which 4 people can be seated in a set-up having 7 chairs in a row

Question 2 :- Number of ways in which 4 chairs in a row can be occupied if there are 7 people present in the room.

Additional information :- In both the cases, a person can sit only in one chair and one chair can accomodate only one person.

---

I often face difficulty in deciding for which entity do I need to find the ways :-

My thought process for Question 1:-

No. of chairs for 1st person to sit = 7

No. of chairs for 2nd person to sit = 6

No. of chairs for 3rd person to sit = 5

No. of chairs for 4th person to sit = 4

which gives me total number of ways as $7*6*5*4$ ways

Question 2:-

Here I did :-

No. of people for 1st chair = 7

No. of people for 2nd chair = 6

No. of people for 3rd chair = 5

No. of people for 4 th chair = 4

which gives me $7*6*5*4$ .   However this answer differs in the way it is presented in my textbook, which gives it as 7!/3! .  I am not sure how we arrive at this , though numerically it is matching.  Please let me know whether my thought process is correct and what does 7!/3! mean here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in both cases your solution is correct. Note that in either case you have a set $A$ with four elements and to each one you want to asssign them an element belonging to a set $B$ with seven elements, moreover, no element of $B$ can correspond to two or more elements of $A$. In more mathematical terms, such a map from $A$ to $B$ is called an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). So regardless of how you interpret the elements of $A$ (either as persons or chairs) you can map them injectively to $B$ in $7\times6\times5\times4 = 840$ ways.

Furthermore, note that $n! = n\times(n-1) \times \ldots\times1$ so $\frac{7!}{3!} = \frac{7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2\times1}{3\times2\times1} = 7\times6\times5\times4$ so the way it was presented in your textbook is a more convenient way of expressing your result. Moreover, you are picking [a k-element subset of an n-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) and the amount of such permutations are more commonly expressed as either $P(n,k)$ or as seen in your textbook.